# Mongoose+Node API delays db query

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

GET works great, DEL works great too.
but POST... :
What happens is that string goes in db. It does not show up(on my webapp).
When I add a second string, it finally shows up. As if there is a delay?

```
 app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
    todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : true
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    });
        todo.find(function(err, todos){
    if(err)
        res.send(err)
    res.json(todos);
 });
```

But if I do it with delete, it works like normal. deleted the id and show the rest of the id's.

```
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res){
    todo.remove({
        _id : req.params.todo_id,
    }, function(err, todo){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
});
    todo.find(function(err, todos){
        if(err)
                res.send(err)
        res.json(todos);
        });
});
```

I hope my question makes sense, I'm not so good at english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting that node is asynchronous.  In your post function it's quite probable that your find function is executing before the create function completes.

At the very least you'll want to refactor your functions so the find happens in the callback function called from the create.

You would rewrite the post function like so:

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
    todo.create({
        text: req.body.text,
        done: true
    }, function (err, todo) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        todo.find(function (err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        })
    })
});
```

However, this can lead to the "callback hell" node is famous for.  People often use the async library: The most common thing to do is to use the async library: https://github.com/caolan/async or promises to avoid nesting callbacks.

Nesting just once isn't too bad, though.

Comment: **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**
is the result, with node quitting. therefore I worked around it, but clearly that doesn't result in what I want. So what's left for me now is this annoying error that I really don't get.
should I instead ask that in a new question?

Comment: yes probably, but it sounds like your database connection isn't set up right or is not running where you think it is :).

Comment: after submitting and getting the error, the data however is submitted to the database. weird. but thanks man for the very quick reply!!

Comment: cool. yeh you answered it(with a bit missing braces and stuff but i get it)